# I want to type and save the Kannada text from my Angular project

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have html form which calls API and saves the text field in database. In this text I can type the Kannada words. But while rendering the list, the Kannada fonts are displayed as `??`.

I would like to how this can be solved.

In the input field, I copy pasted Kannada text and saved.
I used charset before the table list.

`<meta charset=utf-8>`

Please help.

Comment: What database do you use? Does it support utf-8?

Comment: I use Mysql Db and yes it does support utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the [ISO 639-1](https://localizely.com/iso-639-1-list/) Kannada language code like this:

```
<html lang="kn">...</html>
```